# what is the difference between these two in swift 3

Tags: swift

we can return a string like below :

```
 var dogName : String {
        return "my dog name"
    }
```

as well as below :

```
func returndogName() -> String {
        return "my dog name"
    }
```

basically these two does the same. it returns a string. the only I got is the second one is a function type and first one is not. is that the only difference or are there any other differences with this. and are there any advantages between these two. that means which is the best.

Comment: These are not same.

Comment: One is a function and another is a variable

Comment: @user3575114 OP is talking about the functionality. Like as var it returns the string as well from the func it also returns the same string .

Comment: @MoinShirazi: This question is *not* specific to the changes in version 3 of Swift.